# Multi-plot grid with markers and proper legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to construct a 2x2 multi-plot grid of line plots that has both markers and a legend. My first attempt uses `FacetGrid` and `sns.lineplot`. Since the second row of the multi-plot grid has a slightly different range of x values, I also do not want a shared x-axis.

Sample data:

```
def gen_data(xvalues):
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(xvalues=xvalues*3,
                        datacategory=[1]*30+[2]*30+[3]*30,
                       yvalues=np.random.randn(90).cumsum()))

row1 = pd.concat([gen_data(list(range(30))), gen_data(list(range(30)))], keys=["col1","col2"], names=["mycol"])
row2 = pd.concat([gen_data(list(range(1,60,2))), gen_data(list(range(1,60,2)))], keys=["col1","col2"], names=["mycol"])
selected_df = pd.concat([row1, row2], keys=["row1", "row2"], names=["myrow"])
selected_df = selected_df.reset_index()
```

Plotting code

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(selected_df, col="mycol", row="myrow", hue="datacategory",
                  margin_titles=True, sharex=False)
g = g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, x="xvalues", y="yvalues",
                    style="datacategory", markers=True, dashes=False, ci="sd")
g.add_legend()
```

Generated plot:

[image: Generated plot]

This gives me a 2x2 multi-plot grid with markers, but the colors of the legend are all black. Removing `style="datacategory"` corrects the colors in the legend, but removes the markers.

I made a second attempt with `relplot` but found out that it does not support disabling `sharex`.

```
g = sns.relplot("xvalues", "yvalues", data=selected_df,
               col="mycol", row="myrow",
                kind="line", hue="datacategory", style="datacategory",
                ci="sd", markers=True, dashes=False)
```

Generated plot:

[image: Generated plot] (I'm not sure what datacategory 0 is, but it's not a problem with my real data)

Except for not having a shared x-axis, this gets very close to what I want, and more: It gives different markers to different data categories too (great!).

I considered `catplot`, but the data is not categorical and I wish to draw line plots.

How do you make a 2x2 multi-plot grid of line plots that has markers, does not share an x-axis, and has a legend?

Comment: can you provide a minium working example of your code?

Comment: @Alessandro I'd be happy to, is there a data set available suitable for line plotting?

Comment: You can create a mock-up dataset `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` that suits what you want to show here.

Comment: Added example data and plots